# Using jqPlot to fill the bottom half of a graph with a color

Tags: javascript, canvas, jqplot

I'm using jqPlot to make a simple graph:

[image]

Their documentation states that it's very out of date. Is there a way to shade the lower half of the graph (below the line) with a color such as this one?

http://www.epmag.com/resources/images/archives/OFFPROD-Petrolite-Graph1.jpg

If not, any clues on how I could shade it myself? jqPlot uses javascript to draw on an HTML canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your [series options](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Series.fill) set:

```
series: [
    {
       fill: true
    }
]
```

See this [example](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/dashboardWidget.html).

Comment: How can I prevent the hover change?

Comment: What do you mean by "hover change"?

Comment: Got it figured out. By default, when you hover over the graph, it becomes a bit lighter. Fixed with a rendering option change.